# Magento 2.3 insert a product into a specific store

Tags: product, magento2.3, store-view

i have Magento 2.3 and i create three different store view with different ID.
After i created a product i can change the price, the name ecc... by the select on the upper-left.
But when i create a product i can't specify where publish it.

For example : i have product A and product B. i have store 1 and store 2. I wanna publish only on store2 the product B.

How can i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to your admin panel and Open `Catalog > Products > click to add new product button > And opend the product page` like

[image]

And after add your content and click to save button.

save product and see upper-left select your particular store And again save.

[image]

Finally run ---

```
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:f
```

And check vidoes for more infomation ---

**https://www.loom.com/share/9407835364a24ce0b84558b066d74779**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Great. Thank you so much

Comment: this answer helpful or not.If yes, So accept and upvote because other community help...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert product for specific store, its simple as to select option "Products In Websites" from back end at the time of product creation.

A product will be created for the specific store only.

[image: Select Product in Website options]